# Using Selector with JSOUP and DOM

Tags: java, jsoup

After reading through the documentation.

Ive come to realize the selector method is what i need to be able to scan different html sources(such as webpages) to retreive certain tags.

For example. I have a list of htmls that have articles.

when a item is clicked in the listview, the html is parsed for certain tags to extract the article text.

I know the Selector method would allow me to set a pattern.

But what is the right format for what i am trying to do for the selector method?

Comment: Is this android related ? The Jsoup docs explain it pretty well. I have an app with jSoup in Android and it works fine, you should not have any problem at all.

Comment: Im not having a problem with it. Right now i am using doc.getElementsByAttributeValue I want to set a pattern that the doc.selecter looks for in all of the articles it is given. To retreive the text and image:src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But what is the right format for what i am trying to do for the selector method?*

It should be in [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) syntax. Jsoup also supports some additional pseudoselectors. You can find them all in this [cookbook documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) and in the [`Selector` API documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

If you're having problems with figuring the right selector for your functional requirement, then just press `Ask Question` button here and elaborare in detail what HTML you have and point out what part exactly you want to extract. This way we can post an answer showing the desired selector syntax.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042262/how-to-create-jsoup-selector-for-the-following