# How to create JSOUP selector for the following

Tags: java, jsoup

For example I want to extract the text in this article HTML:

```
    <div class="description">
            <div style="clear: none;" class="post-fb-like">
              <fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" href="http://mashable.com/2011/08/07/3-handy-mobile-apps/" send="true" width="625" height="61"><span><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=116628718381794&amp;channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df138585052991e8%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmashable.com%252Ff15a8eb75cc2b58%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2011%2F08%2F07%2F3-handy-mobile-apps%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=en_US&amp;node_type=link&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=true&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=625" class="fb_ltr" title="Like this content on Facebook." style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 29px; width: 625px;" name="f2d40595a65cf36" id="f24fece5e565ec4" scrolling="no"></iframe></span></fb:like>
            </div>
                        <p><img src="http://ec.mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/bizspark2.gif" alt="" align="left"><em>The <a href="http://mashable.com/tag/bizspark">Spark of Genius Series</a> highlights a unique feature of startups and is made possible by <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.microsoftstartupzone.com/BizSpark/Pages/At_a_Glance.aspx?WT.mc_id=MSZ_Mashable_posts" target="_blank">Microsoft BizSpark</a>. If you would like to have your startup considered for inclusion, please see the details <a href="http://mashable.com/bizspark/">here</a>.</em></p>

<p><img src="http://5.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/mobile-devices.jpg" alt="" title="mobile devices" class="alignright" height="141" width="225">Each <a href="http://mashable.com/follow/topics/startup-weekend-roundup">weekend</a>, <em>Mashable</em> hand-picks startups we think are building interesting, unique or niche products. </p>
<p>This week, we’ve rounded up startups making mobile applications that bridge the physical and digital worlds for improved communication and enhanced experiences. </p>
<p>TransFire breaks down global communication barriers with its instant and automatic translation capabilities, while Babbleville facilitates neighbor-to-neighbor communication around events or topics. And, Picdish uses time and place to bring friends together over shared mobile food experiences.</p>
<hr>
```

And I have another HTML page I want to extract text from too, but its in different format. I want to extract this text from http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/europe/08/12/uk.riots.dan.rivers/index.html?hpt=hp_c2

How would I go about creating a selector to extract the text no matter which article url is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How would I go about creating a selector to extract the text no matter which article url is given?*

You can't. All websites have their own HTML structure. Open the page in the webbrowser yourself, rightclick and *View Source*. Look. You should create a separate selector for each individual website.

For your first example, assuming that it's the *whole* HTML, the text is thus inside those `<p>` tags. You can then use

```
Document html = Jsoup.parse(yourHtmlString);
Elements paragraphs = html.select("p");
String text = paragraphs.text();
// ...
```

For your CNN site, according the HTML source you'd like to get all `<p>`s of the `<div class="cnn_strycntntlft">`, so this selector should do:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/europe/08/12/uk.riots.dan.rivers/index.html?hpt=hp_c2").get();
Elements paragraphs = document.select(".cnn_strycntntlft p");
String text = paragraphs.text();
// ...
```

By the way, it would be easier to just use their RSS feeds instead of parsing the whole HTML. Lot of news sites provides RSS feeds for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Thats funny that you said that becauses thats EXACTLY what i am trying to do. I have a list of rss feed sites, When one is clicked the rss feed titles are loaded into a list and when a rss item is clicked the url is loaded into a webview. Instead of being loaded into a webview i want the html to be parsed getting the article text and maybe some images instead of loading it into a web browser on android

Comment: SO from what i described in the comment What would be the best way to this?

Comment: So.. You're saying that the RSS feed items which you have points to the HTML page of the other site instead of a RSS feed of the other site? You could then use Jsoup to extract the RSS feed link from the HTML page. Something like `String rssUrl = document.select("link[rel=alternate][type=application/rss+xml]").attr("href");` and then send a new request on that RSS URL.

Comment: For example... Here is a rss feed http://cgi.askmen.com/RSS/askmenRSS_channel.php?ID=sports When the links are clicked it forwards you to the url. Instead of going to the url i want to parse whatever the html is for that url to get the text from it and some image src.

Comment: You should really do it on a per-site basis. There is no single generic super magic omniscent God selector which extracts *exactly* that data you want from an arbitrary site. Best what you could do is to maintain a `Map<String, String>` which holds all selectors on a per-site basis. Or you should look for a RSS feed which only links to other RSS feeds, not HTML pages.

Comment: Do you think this is a big deal to a user to not be forwarded to a html site? But instead have the text streamed right into a textview?

Comment: I may be putting to much focus on something un-needed

Comment: Would it be possible to go through all my sites and create a selector for each one? The only thing that changes is the rss feeds. The websites never change

Comment: Yes, that was what I was suggesting with the `Map`. Use for example the site domain name as key and the selector as value.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Uh, what part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: The part where you are saying Map. Could you provide an example of what you are saying to do with it?

Comment: Uh, something like `Map<String, String> selectors = new HashMap<String, String>(); selectors.put("http://www.cnn.com", ".cnn_strycntntlft p"); // Etc..` and then to use it, do `String selector = selectors.get(domainname); Elements elements = document.select(selector); // Etc..`. Learn about maps here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: so <String, String> Should be??

Comment: Uh yes, key and value are just strings. Are you new to Java in general? I'd suggest to work yourself through some basic Java tutorials/book.

Comment: Just started android about 4 months ago..But let me ask you this..Do you think for my rss feed should i parse the html that the feed link goes to for the user, or should i just load it in a webview?

Comment: Depends on business requirements. Talk with your customer and/or (potential) endusers.

Comment: Okay thanks Alot for all of your help. Alot of my fans like how it is. I was trying to be alittle facier. lol